# web.config Redirect rule not working in IE and FireFox

Tags: url-rewriting, web-config

I have two domains **baddomain.com** and **gooddomain.com** which are pointing to the same hosting service. I have bought SSl certificate and now I want to redirect Bad one to the good one which has SSL installed. I wrote these rules and it works on Chrome but not in IE and firefox. Bad domain redirects to **https** instead of redirecting to good domain. Thanks.

```
 <!--Redirect from bad domain to good one-->
<rule name="BadtoGood" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="baddomain.com" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://gooddomain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>             

<!--Force https on good domain -->
<rule name="forceHTTPS" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="*" negate="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://gooddomain.com/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that I had enabled **force https** through the website control panel and it was overriding the downstream settings in web.config.

In my case this was the path:

Plesk for windows **>** Websites and domains **>** Hosting setting